# How to add serial number in recycling list items

Tags: android, listview, android-cursoradapter

I have a custom `ListView` and used `CursorAdapter` to expose data from a Cursor. One challenge I got was to add Serial number in each List Items. I know there has to be a column named "_id" and It's a primary field.

What I could do is add Serial number by grabbing up the value of "_id" column, But It was not possible because I showed all data in descending order.

Another way I tried was by declaring a variable and added 1 each time the item is created.

My `Adapter` class which extends `CursorAdapter` simply looks like this

```
public class BalanceInfoAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    Context context;
    List<Balance> listOfBalance;

    int serialNo = 0; //Declared as field

   //Some constructers to initialise fields

@Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {

        serialNo+=1; //Added +1 to the variable

        return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(
                R.layout.myLayout, parent, false);
    }

@Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

      mySerialNumberTextView.setText(String.valueOf(serialNo)); //Shown Serial Number in a TextView of List Item

}
```

**Problem**

It worked fine till List Items fills the screen at first time. But as I scroll down and up, the way I mentioned above failed, because `CursorAdapter` recycles it's List Items as it is scrolled and Serial Number of first item became most higher.

**Question**

- Is there any other way to add S/N in recycling List Items ? OR I can prevent this from happening in the same `Adapter` class.

Comment: Why is the ordering causing problems with using the sqlite _id field?  It should be OK to use _id even with ordering in a query.

Comment: _id didn't affect anything. But I exposed list in descending order with another column. Then data of _id column will be random and not usable in this case.

Comment: The _id column will never be random.  Why would you think that?  Sqlite assigns column ids that don't change EVER per row.  They just won't appear sequentially if you order by some other field.

Comment: @DougStevenson I was trying to tell the same. yes They just won't appear sequentially.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the **public abstract int getPosition ()** method of Cursor.

For more reference click [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getPosition())

eg: int rowNum = cursor.getPosition();

Note: in **public abstract void bindView (View view, Context context, Cursor cursor)** method of CursorAdapter, cursor automatically moves to the current row.
So using cursor we can get the current row position in .

Comment: getPosition just returns the position of the current row relative to the current data set.  That could change from query to query as items are added and removed.  It's not clear to me if the OP wants that behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Picking up from the documentation http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html#newView%28android.content.Context,%20android.database.Cursor,%20android.view.ViewGroup%29

```
 public abstract View newView (Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent)
```

cursor -    The cursor from which to get the data. The cursor is already moved to the correct position.

So here cursor is already at its correct position. So you can use cursor.getPosition() method to get the correct serial number.